# Move a 3D object while keeping its exact 3D orientation in After Effects

Tags: layers, 3d, adobe-after-effects

This is probably findable on Google, but I don't know the right terms to search. I have an 3D layer. If I move that 3D layer it will change orientation visually while the values stay the same.

Example (watch the blue arrow):
[image]

So how I keep it's original rotation anywhere on the canvas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are essentially asking is how to make the camera orthographic. Unfortunately AfterEffects does not allow you to make true orthographic cameras. However in this case you do not really have to as that is just a 2D pan and you can use pre-composed 3D imagery turned flat as @Alin described.

You can also dispense the camera and rotate the 3d object and view it form the front view. Then just move the object about, no perspective added. Obviously now you need to rotate the object in relation to your scene which is a bit unpractical in many cases.

This gets a bit tricky if you want to reserve the right to rotate the object and camera. What you can do is make a perspective camera with a very very small angle that is very far away. This approximates orthographic cameras very well. So if you make the angle of view 1 degree or even less then the image exhibits very little perspective distortion.

Comment: Thanks for finding the right words that I was missing! I did the perspective camera trick and it works well and easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

Just tested this. Simply Pre-compose the 3D layers and animate the pre-comp instead. You can animate it however you want, not only left-right.

[image]

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Well, it's a 3D object in an environment with a camera...that's how it should look (perspective). You can fake the effect of it moving moving the background instead.

A workaround to what you need is to **not** make it a 3D in AE, make it a 3D in Illustrator and import it to AE without making it a 3D layer in AE. This way you have a flattened layer with a 3D aspect that will meet your requirements.

You can always go back to the AI you imported, change the text, save and Reload Footage in AE and it will update.

I am not sure if AE has a **flatted** or **expand / expand appearance** function to avoid switching between AE and AI.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This was only an example. I want it to have way more excessive movement than it just going from left to right unfortunately. So just flattening it wouldn't be good solution in my case. Maybe if I make the layer the same size as the object and then importing the layer in another layer.. would that work?

Comment: @GerlofLeuhof  Updated my answer. I have found a way to do this just in AI. Simply pre-comp your 3D Layers. (added gif to show)

Comment: Nice! That works. For now I used @joojaa's solution. Can't seem to tick both answers as correct, sorry!

Comment: @GerlofLeuhof No worries :) It can only be one answer marked as correct :) Glad you could sort it out.